# VB.NET Crystal Report not showing MySQL Date

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a crystal report dynamically from my `MySQL` database.

My code is....

```
Try
        OpenConnection()

        qry = "SELECT * FROM sales LEFT JOIN salesdetails ON salesdetails.InvoiceId = sales.InvoiceId WHERE salesdetails.InvoiceId='" & TbInvNo.Text & "' AND sales.InvoiceId='" & TbInvNo.Text & "'"
        Dim dbcommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim dbadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim stdata As New DataSet()
        dbcommand.Connection = conn
        dbcommand.CommandText = qry
        dbadapter.SelectCommand = dbcommand
        dbadapter.Fill(stdata)
        stdata.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath & "\ReportXml\bill.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

        Dim objRpt As New NormalSaleBill
        objRpt.SetDataSource(stdata.Tables(0))

        FormReport.RptViewer.ReportSource = objRpt
        FormReport.ShowDialog()
        FormReport.RptViewer.RefreshReport()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try
```

Everything is ok in my generated `Crystal Report` except the `InvoiceDate` field. It is not showing anything. When I open the xml file I found the below in InvoiceDate field.

```
<xs:element name="InvoiceDate" msdata:DataType="MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" />
```

I searched and found a similar question [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?33,259885,259925#msg-259925). It was told that the above must be changed by

```
<xs:element name="InvoiceDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
```

But I don't know how to do it.

How could I solve this ? I tried to find the solution but failed.

**I have updated my code where I did not convert my date into string**

### Update (17/11/2014):

I have removed `Allow Zero Datetime` from my `ConnectionString` but the result is same.

### Update (18/11/2014) :

I found something that at least resolves my problem. I do not know if this is the ultimate solution.

```
DATE_FORMAT(sales.InvoiceDate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS InvoiceDate
```

I am modifying the SQL Query from

```
SELECT * FROM
```

to

```
Select
sales.InvoiceId,
DATE_FORMAT(sales.InvoiceDate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS InvoiceDate,......
```

and so on. **Here I have to write more than the previous query stating all the fields I need**.

This resolves the problem. Please tell me if this is the ultimate solution or there are other ways to do this.

Comment: dont convert your dates to string if you want them to act like dates.  #11/11/2014# evaluates differently than "11/11/2014".  What is the column data type?

Comment: The Column datatype is `DateTime`

Comment: a) leave the From/To variables as DateTime types b) use SQL parameters, c) create instances for your forms; your query may well be failing (see a and b) in addition to anything else.

Comment: I am giving you another snippets.

Comment: Plutonix, I have updated my code in my question description. Here I did not converted my date into string. But the result is same above.

Comment: Instead of writing just the schema to XML, write the data too. Then look to make sure you have data for that field. This might help you see something. Also, The field name does not exist in both tables, does it?

Comment: The field exists in both the tables. For your information, I am writing the data also inside the `xml` file by retrieving it from the database. This is why I said, all the fields are ok except the date.